# How can I test token-based authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need some help with testing the following.  I am doing the RailsCast about securing an api:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api?view=asciicast

I have a `RequestController` with a `before_filter` to check if the request has a token:

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

  before_filter :restrict_access
  respond_to :json

#...

def authenticate
    return restrict_access
  end

  private
  def restrict_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
    end
  end

end
```

My failing rspec test looks like:

```
it 'responds successfully to generic request because of key protection' do
    api_key = ApiKey.create
    api_key.save!

    get :index
    request.headers["token"] = api_key.access_token
    expect(response).to be_success # test for the 200 status-code
end
```

with result: `expected success? to return true, got false`

I don't understand how I can inject the valid api_key in to the request so that the response will evaluate to true.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Token Authentication expects a `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header in this format:

```
Token token="my-api-token"
```

Also, you'll want to set the header before the `get :index` line:

```
request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = "Token token=\"#{api_key.access_token}\""
get :index
```

You can use the `encode_credentials` method instead if you prefer:

```
request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials(api_key.access_token)
```

Comment: can I arbitrarily name other `.headers[]` values?  For example, can I do `request.headers["username"] = "Joe"` and then reference it in my controller with `request.headers["username"]`?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add the closing bracket after access_token in the second example.